# How to match perfectly the camera with the 3D environment recreated from the original pictures of a movie with fspy

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I've recreated the 3D representation of the environment that I've seen on the movie "the man from earth". I'm talking about the interior of the house and the exterior,the surrounding environment. Below you can see a picture of the interior :

[image: camera starting point]

Next I placed the blender on the same position of the camera in the real movie and I have recreated the movements. Below you can see which kind of movements :

[original camera movements](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LVcXsD69g4wxYrpGnZIQlzjE9yYfwgr-)

then I added an empty with the original images sequence of the movie's section,because I want to have the image references when later I will pose the characters :

[image: 3]

what's the problem ? that I'm not able to match the camera,the section of the interior with the empty linked with the images references. Is there a way to do that without modifying the geometry of the interior ? Maybe only resizing,scaling and translating the camera and/or the empty ? Below you see that I tried to do that,but unsuccesfully :

[failed try](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1izz9PAkzys-3Icw-7qoZ_3Zmr_1KIby8)

thanks.

Comment: The way you're trying to achieve it is set for failure. Use the video clip as Background Image, set Axis to Camera, set voodoo camera as active camera and then try to match the view.

Comment: I imagine that It will never match perfectly.